# updating 2 table column at the same time, laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I've been working on this for quite a while now, this problem is composed on eloquent relationships on Laravel 5.4, in this case, what I want to do is that, to accept verification of the user, and update its verif_level(column name from users) to level '2', now, the structure of the verification_accounts table consists of its id, and user_id, which is a foreign key from the users table. Now, everything works fine, but the id of the verif_level being updated on the users table is the same as the id of the verification_accounts table is 9 and its user_id is 9459, the data updated on the users table is also 9 which has the same value on the verification_accounts table. which supposed to be 9459's verif_level to be updated to level 2, here is the code for the controller:

```
 public function updateVerification(Request $request) 
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'admin_feedback' => 'required', 
    ]);
    $verification = VerificationAccount::find($request->id)->load('user');
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    if ($validator->passes())
        if($verification->verification_level == '1'){
            $verification->status = 1;
            $verification->proccessed_by = \Auth::user()->id;
            $verification->admin_feedback = $request->admin_feedback;
            $verification->save();
            $user->verif_level = '2';
            $user->save();
            return  response()->json(['success' => true,'message' => 'Verification successfully updated']);
        }
        else{
            return  response()->json(['success' => false,'message' => 'Verification already accepted']);
        }
    else{
        return ['error' => $validator->errors()];
    }
}
```

but when I do "$request->user_id", it returns an error of creating an array of empty object. and idea how to deal with this?

Comment: You're using `VerificationAccount::find($request->id)` and `User::find($request->id)`, which looks like an error. This is implying that both the `VerificationAccount` and `User` records have the same id. Is that correct? Also, if you're using `->load('user')`, you shouldn't have to query for it after the fact.

Comment: HI, I've solved it already, this was on my form upon sending the submit button, my form data doesn't have user_id on it, my bad. but thanks for letting me know